# "Return" outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this question is very noobish, but my program keeps telling me that "Return" outside function.

So what it should do is if the user presses "Enter" it should stop. Otherwise it should continue asking and resolving the input.

I would like to know how do I do like in the I want a new `function test_pig()` that should put in the input the words : `happy, duck, glove, evil,eight,yowler,crystal`

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
if sentence==[]:
        return
vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y")
words =  sentence.split()

def pig(word):
    for u in range(len(word)):
        if word[u] in vowels:
                          return u
    return -1
for word in words:
    vowel = pig(word)

    if(word[0] == 'y'):
             print(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay", ' ', end='')
    elif(vowel == -1):
             print(word, ' ', end='')
    elif(vowel == 0):
             print(word + "way", ' ', end='')
    else:
             print(word[vowel:] + word[:vowel] + "ay", ' ', end='')
```

Comment: Is this your actual indentation?

Comment: Yes this is my actual indentation

Comment: Use consistent indentation in your code—4 spaces for each indent level, not sometimes 4 spaces, sometimes a tab, sometimes 4 spaces and a tab. Occasionally, you'll get away with it and it won't cause a problem, but you definitely shouldn't count on that, because when it _does_ cause a problem (which I'd give 5:1 odds is what happened when you tried my answer) it's impossible to see why. Most editors can be configured to always insert spaces even when you hit the tab key. And run Python with the `-tt` flag (like `python -tt myscript.py` instead of just `python myscript.py`) to catch the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit the whole program, you need to use `exit()`, not `return`. The `return` statement can only be used inside a function. Which is why you get an error saying exactly that when you try it on your third line.

But normally you put your "main code" at the end of the script, meaning that you usually don't need `exit`. For example, here's some code that will keep asking for input and calling `pig` on it until the user hits enter:

```
vowels = # etc.

def pig(word):
    # your definition here

while True:
    sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
    if not sentence:
        break
    words = sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        # your for-loop code here
```

The `break` will exit the loop, and there's no code after the loop, so the script just finishes successfully.

There are other problems with your code, but this will get you past the first one.

---

As a side note, the reason I changed your `if sentence==[]` to `if not sentence` is that `sentence` is a string, and no string is *ever* equal to an empty list. You could check for an empty *string* instead, like `if sentence == ''`. But it's simpler, and more pythonic, to just check for emptiness with `not`.

Comment: This just prints input until I press enter

Comment: So it doesn't print the result of the input

Comment: @user3026270: If you take exactly what I put above, copy and paste the code indicated by the comments, and run it, it definitely does print the result of the input. You can see it doing so [here](http://ideone.com/FPlnB9). So obviously you did something wrong, but if you don't show me your code, I can't tell you _what_ you did wrong.

Comment: @user3026270: If you want me to guess, I suspect you used a mix of tabs and spaces (as you did in your original post), so the `if` ended up all the way outside the `while` loop as far as Python's concerned, even though it looks like it's inside the `for` loop to any human reader. So, it reads your input, pigs each word, and repeats forever… and then, only after forever is over, it prints the results.